# How to change user interface of cell content in a table with JQuery/Classic ASP?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I've a list with columns. And in one column I want to change the user interface of a text with a specific value. How do you that?

By example a text with a value 'Green' and I will give this cell a class clsGreen. (I'm not well known with JQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".column4").each(function (index) {
            var content = $(this).text().replace(
            "<%= "Green" %>", "<span class='clsGreen'><%= "Green" %> </span>").replace(
            "<%= "Red" %>", "<span class='clsRed'><%= "Red" %></span>");
            $(".column4").html(content);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Do u want to change the appearance of the text or the text value itself?

Comment: The appearance of the text.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
             $("table#MyTable tbody tr").find("td:eq("4")").each(function () {
                   if ($(this).text() == "Green") {
                          $(this).addClass("clsGreen");
                   } else if ($(this).text() == "Red") {
                          $(this).addClass("clsRed");
                   }
             });
          });
   </script>
```